# Sizes of application windows are not remembered each time the app is launched

Tags: window

Kubuntu 12.04 standard install, kernel is 3.2.0-34-generic.

1. I launch an application (specific application is irrelevant as this issue occurs with all of them).
2. I maximize the window, or move it to a specific location on the screen.
3. I close the application.
4. The next time I launch the app, the window is back at its original size and location.

If any further information is required.

Answer (score 0):

Specific application is important, actually. This is something applications have to deal with themselves, generally, and most don't.